# How to get my next elif statements to print?

Tags: python

Here is my code for the question.

```
print('=================================================================================================\n')

prompt = input(f'''\tYou and your family are camping out in a forest near the tetons.
Once the sun goes down and your campground is dark you and your family decide to go to
bed but all of you forgot to light a fire and there are no lamps to light the way. However you find
a {'MATCH'} and a {'FLASHLIGHT'}. Which one do you pick up? ''').lower()
print('-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n')

RUN = ''
HIDE = ''
match = ''
if prompt.lower() == 'match':
    match = input(f'''\tYou pick up the match and strike it, and for an instant, the forest around you is
    illuminated. You see a large grizzly bear, and then the match burns out.
    Do you want to {'RUN'} or {'HIDE'} behind a tree? ''').lower()
elif match.lower() == 'RUN':
    RUN = print(f'''gfsfdg ''')
elif match.lower() == 'HIDE':
    HIDE = input(f'''fgsbsgf ''')
```

Comment: You’re doing .lower() = “HIDE”. HIDE is in capitals, it will never be equal. Change that to “hide”

Comment: Off-topic (whatever the heck that is): None of the f-strings you have accomplish anything — so why are you using them? You're also using triple-quoted string in a number of spots that don't need them… Use of either only makes your code less readable, so shouldn't be using unless necessary IMO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a if/elif/else structure the first condition to match will stop evaluation of the following conditions.

In your code that means that when prompt.lower() == "match" is true then the elif are just ignored.

You need to put your tests on match.lower() in another if/elif structure.

Answer (score 0):

You just want `match.upper()` or to switch the comparison string to lowercase!

```py
>>> match = "run"
>>> match.lower() == 'RUN'
False
>>> match.upper() == 'RUN'
True
```

Comment: I have the .lower() so that the input coming from the user will not affect the output of the code. I think that my problem is coming from not having my variables set correctly

Comment: `.upper()` and `.lower()` _return_ the value, rather than setting it once - the issue is that then you _compare_ the return with an uppercase string (when it's necessarily lowercase)